# CollectionView - Drop pdf file onto collectionView (loadObject(ofClass:) not working properly)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I have a problem loading a pdf file from a drop session (using [`UICollectionView`'s Drag&Drop feature](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/supporting_drag_and_drop_in_collection_views)).

Inside `collectionView(_:performDropWith:coordinator)`, I want to load the dropped items on a background thread:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
    // I'm dropping a valid pdf file from the Files app in iOS.

    // I'm using performBackgroundTask because I want to save stuff to the database
    appDelegate.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask({ (privateContext) in
        for item in coordinator.items {      

            // This correctly returns true      
            if item.dragItem.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: MyPDFDocument.self) {

                item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: MyPDFDocument.self) { (pdfItem, error) in
                   // This is not called
                }

            }
        }
     })

}

final class MyPDFDocument: PDFDocument, NSItemProviderReading {

    public static var readableTypeIdentifiersForItemProvider: [String] {
        return [kUTTypePDF as String]
    }

    public static func object(withItemProviderData data: Data, typeIdentifier: String) throws -> ComicBookPDFDocument {
        return MyPDFDocument(data: data)!
    }

}
```

However, it is not working. The block `loadObject(ofClass:)` is supposed to be calling, is simply not called. It is working perfectly fine on the main thread.

The thing is, I cannot to put the `performBackgroundTask` block inside `loadObject(ofClass:)` (then the dropped objects load perfectly), because if you drop multiple pdf files, this causes merge errors when saving the context (because the background tasks run simultaneously for every dropped file).

Any ideas what's going on here? Is it not allowed to load objects from within another thread?

Comment: I know this is old... but what did you end up doing in the end? I am having the same problem and it's very odd.

Comment: So, it's been a long time since I had this problem. I think I did find a way. I'm going to post an answer. Maybe it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I looked at the code, but I hope this helps:

The solution for me was to use the method `loadObjects(ofClass:completion:)`. This grabs all objects of the desired files asynchronously. This is not stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidropsession/2891058-loadobjects). However, if you cmd-click the method and go to its declaration, there's this comment:

```swift
/* A convenience method that can be used only during the UIDropInteractionDelegate's
     * implementation of `-dropInteraction:performDrop:`.
     * Asynchronously instantiates objects of the provided class for each
     * drag item that can do so. The completion handler is called on the
     * main queue, with an array of all objects that were created, in the
     * same order as `items`.
     * The progress returned is an aggregate of the progress for all objects
     * that are loaded.
     */
    func loadObjects(ofClass aClass: NSItemProviderReading.Type, completion: @escaping ([NSItemProviderReading]) -> Void) -> Progress
```

After instantiating the objects, the completion handler is called on the main queue. From here, you can dispatch to a background queue and do whatever you want with the files.

I grabbed the code I ended up with and simplified it:

```swift
// ValidComicBookFile is my NSItemProviderReading type that accepts multiple file types, like archive and pdf
coordinator.session.loadObjects(ofClass: ValidComicBookFile.self) { (importedObjects) in
    guard let validComicBookFiles = importedObjects as? [ValidComicBookFile] else {
        // Handle errors
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        // ...
        for (index, file) in validComicBookFiles.enumerated() {
            switch file.fileType {
            case .archive:
                // Unpack it and stuff
            case .pdf:
                // For example:
                if let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(data: file.data) {
                    pdfs.append(pdfDoc) // Append it to an array I created earlier
                }
            case .none:
                break
            }
        }
        // ...
    }    
}
```

One note: I didn't end up needing to save to the database, but this way, it shouldn't be a problem (hopefully).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a try!